# How to save CSV file from query in psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, psycopg2

I'm trying to save in a local .csv the results of query performed in python towards a PostgreSQL database (using psycopg2).

I'm able to print the result of the query in the console, but fail to export it to a csv file.

I've tried using the copy_to function, but even with the [documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from) I can't figure it out:

```
    # Retrieve the records from the database with query
    cursor.execute("SELECT col1 FROM myDB.myTable WHERE col1 > 2")
    records = cursor.fetchall()

    # Save to csv with copy_to
    io = open('copy_to.csv', 'w')
    cursor.copy_to(io, 'records', ',')
    print("Copied records from query into file object using sep = ,")
    io.close()
```

This provokes the error *"psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "records" does not exist".*

Is there a better way to store the query's result in a local table which could be passed in **copy_to**? Thanks for any tips!

Comment: `copy_to` is really meant to work on entire tables, not queries. Consider using python's [csv library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) or [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) to write the csv file.

Answer (score 5):

I did some more research and here is another solution that might be more likely to work:

````
``` python
import psycopg2

#note the lack of trailing semi-colon in the query string, as per the Postgres documentation
s = "'SELECT col1 FROM myDB.myTable WHERE col1 > 2'"

conn = psycopg2.connect...
db_cursor = conn.cursor()

SQL_for_file_output = "COPY ({0}) TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER".format(s)

WITH Open(filepath/name, 'w') as f_output:
    cur.copy_expert(SQL_for_file_output, f_output)

conn.close()
```
````

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this helps:

```
cursor.copy_to(COPY table TO file syntax)
```

So in your case:

```
cursor.copy_to(COPY records TO io)
```

Answer (score 0):

This does work for me:

```
csv_file = open('myFile.csv', 'w')

cursor = finbot.conn.cursor()
cursor.copy_to(csv_file, 'table_name', sep=",")
```