# python fastapi: I want to get a csv file in return

Tags: fastapi

I have create a fastapi end point. I pass some params and i want to get a csv file. How can i do that. The following is the code.

```
@app.get("/")
async def root(token: str, dbhost: str, port: int, dbname: str ,username: str, passwd: str,table: str):
    con = psycopg2.connect(dbname=dbname, user=username, password=passwd, host=dbhost, port=port)
    cur = con.cursor()
    save = "{}.csv".format(table)
    store = sql.SQL("""COPY {table} TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER""").format(table=sql.Identifier(table),)
    ### --> HOW TO write the store into the save <-------
    con.commit()
    cur.close()
    con.close()
    return csv file ### <- how to return csv file
```

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22776849/how-to-save-results-of-postgresql-to-csv-excel-file-using-psycopg2 ?

Comment: or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41884254/how-to-save-csv-file-from-query-in-psycopg2

Comment: You'll have to use a `FileResponse`. See: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/
If you are asking how to retrieve data from a database and return a `.csv` file, then you'll have to store it temporarily on the server, return it and then delete it

Comment: Why to temporarily store it. Cant i send the csv format data retrieved as a csv file

Answer (score 3):

if you have your `csv` as a `binary` you can use `StreamingResponse` like this:

```py
from fastapi.responses import StreamingResponse

...

    export_media_type = 'text/csv'
    export_headers = {
          "Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename={file_name}.csv".format(file_name=file_name)
    }
    return StreamingResponse(csv_file_binary, headers=export_headers, media_type=export_media_type)
```

if you have your `csv` as a `path` you can use `FileResponse` like this:

```py
from fastapi.responses import FileResponse

...

    return FileResponse(csv_file_path)
```

Comment: My goal is to send the csv format text which comes from sql query as a file to the user.

Comment: you want send as a `text` not a `file`?

Comment: As a file. Not as text. I was thinking text can be sent as a file. Do we have to first store as file.

Comment: `csv_file` . Is this the output from the `sql.SQL("""COPY {table} TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER""").format(table=sql.Identifier(table),)`

Comment: you can use first option without saving a file, `StreamingResponse` work with binary, `FileResponse` work with files and file must be saved first, you can use `io.BytesIO` for store `file` in memory not in `disk`

Answer (score 0):

To return text as a file (e.g. csv):

```py
...
text: str = ...
return StreamingResponse(
    iter([text]),
    media_type='text/csv',
    headers={"Content-Disposition":
             "attachment;filename=<file_name>.csv"})
```

Bonus for pandas DataFrame:

```py
import pandas as pd

...
df = pd.DataFrame(...)
    
output = df.to_csv(index=False)
return StreamingResponse(
    iter([output]),
    media_type='text/csv',
    headers={"Content-Disposition":
             "attachment;filename=<file_name>.csv"})
```